# Google Play Android Publisher Plugin not working

Tags: android, jenkins, google-play

I have followed below forum and tried to upload the builds to Android google play automatically. But this doesn't working. After building it provides the build as 
**Build Artifacts app-release.apk**. Even though I am getting below log error in the console log out put.

```
[android] Emulator did not appear to start; giving up
[android] Stopping Android emulator
$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
Archiving artifacts
Skipping upload to Google Play due to build result
Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

Forums  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Google+Play+Android+Publisher+Plugin

Please advice me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the log, you're attempting to start an Android Emulator during the build.  This is failing, and so the build stops, without attempting to upload to Google Play.

Since the Android Emulator Plugin runs before your build steps (and is failing), I would be surprised that your job is building anything…

If you don't need to run an emulator, try disabling that option.

Comment: If I disable the Emulator, i am getting below error. ---  java.io.IOException: Process working directory 'C:\Jenkins\workspace\Android_CA_Test\Android_CA_Test\app' doesn't exist!

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys You should edit your question to add that information, but with the full stacktrace, as it's not clear where that exception is coming from.